# Find indices of a groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas, indexing, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I have this fake dataset:

[image]

And I want to find how many times a combination of *BirthDate* and *ZipCode* occur, like so:

[image]

Now, my question is **how can I find the positions in the dataset *df* where these occurences happen?** For example, how can I find the position where 2000101 and 08002 are?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How should looks expected output?

Comment: How about `df.groupby('BirthDate',  'ZipCode').apply(lambda x: list(x.index))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) if need aggregate for counts and for index values like list to new column `Pos`:

```
df1 = (df.reset_index()
         .groupby(['BithDate','ZipCode'])
         .agg(RowNumber=('BithDate','size'), Pos = ('index',list)))
```